# Is it possible to power two shafts separately one-way with a single motor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Is it possible to power two shafts separately one way with a single motor?
In other words: if the motor is rotating left is it possible to have one shaft rotate one way with that motor and have the other shaft not move, and if the motor is rotating right to have the other shaft rotating while the first one is still?

The idea is to have an arm be propelled one way by a ratchet on a motor, making it so the motor doesn't have to have a constant force to hold the weight of whatever is on the arm, and to have a ratchet release of sorts that releases the pressure of the pawl allowing it to drop whatever it is holding, and allowing elastics such as rubber bands to pull the arm back to its default position.

I put some pictures up to illustrate my idea sorry about the drawing quality.[image: nip]

Comment: Yes, think about the rear drive sprocket on a bicycle.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?

Comment: add a pinion gear that is larger than the gap between the motor gear and the output gears ... permanently meshed with motor gear ... attached to a short arm that pivots around the motor shaft ... the arm would swing and gear would mesh, depending on the direction the motor turns

Answer (score 1):

The ratchets wrenches have this reversing functionality.

It should be easy to adjust the same mechanism to your job.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a smoother, continuous rotation than what ratchets can offer.
Some 1 way Sprag Clutch bearings would work rather well.

You could then link your motor to the bearing via pulleys or gears, but a far better soloution would be to put the two spragg bearings on the same motor shaft (the other way around from one another).
This way you elimiante the compelexity of gear/pulleys and fixing another two axes, instead its all inline on the same axis.